# In Unity, how do I update a variable with Collision2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game similar to the arcade game Pop the Lock. I want the paddle to reverse direction when the orange circle and the paddle meet and the space key is pressed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PaddleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool rotate;
    Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0,0,1);
    Vector3 pivotPoint = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
    public int speed = 70;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rotate = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (rotate)
        {
            Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0,0,1);
            transform.RotateAround(pivotPoint, axis, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        } else {
            Vector3 axis = new Vector3(0,0,-1);
            transform.RotateAround(pivotPoint, axis, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && collision.gameObject.tag == "Orange")
        {
            Debug.Log("COLLISION");
            bool rotate = false;
        }
        
    }

}
```

This is my current code.

In the debug log, the COLLISION is printed, so I know that it is working, and the orange circle is moving, so that works too. The paddle, however, keeps spinning around in the same direction.

I tried to use a variable in the z part of the axis to change its direction, and on collision it would change between 1 and -1 to reverse its direction, but that kept giving me errors.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to reverse your direction, reverse your speed, not the axis.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: Fun Fact: you are declaring a new, local bool variable `rotate` in `OnCollisionStay2D` which has no relation to the `public bool` member with the same name.

Comment: As @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp says you're using a seperate instance of the variable `rotate`, just remove the 'bool': `rotate = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

Invert your `speed`, not the `axis`.

---

The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) states:

> *Rotates the transform about `axis` passing through `point` in world coordinates by `angle` degrees.*

The documentation also gives an example invocation with a comment we can utilize to further solidify our thought process to use the `angle` parameter to invert the direction:

```cs
// Spin the object around the target at 20 degrees/second.
transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Let's examine the tail end of that comment a bit closer:

> at 20 degrees/second

If you invert that:

> at -20 degrees/second

You can see how this would have the desired effect. As a result, you can simply invert the `speed` at which you're rotating to invert the angle applied:

```cs
float rotationalSpeed = rotate ? speed : -speed;
transform.RotateAround(pivotPoint, axis, rotationalSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```